# Show that $f(x) := g(|x|_2)x$ is a conservative vector field.

Tags: real-analysis

$g: [0,\infty] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$, continuous and $f: \mathbb{R}^N \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^N, f(x) := g(|x|_2)x$. Show that, f is a conservative vector field, i.e. $\exists \Phi \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^N): f = \nabla \Phi$.

What I have got so far:

$f$ consists of $f_i = g(|x|_2)x_i$ for $i=1,...,N$

Let $\Phi(x)=h(|x|_2)$.

It follows, that $\partial_i h(|x|_2) = g(|x|_2)x_i$.

$\partial_i h(|x|_2) = \frac{h'(|x|_2)}{|x|_2}x_i$, so $g(|x|_2) = \frac{h'(|x|_2)}{|x|_2}$ and $h'(|x|_2) = g(|x|_2)|x|_2$.

I have tried to find a function $h: [0, \infty) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$, that complies the rule above and I have found $h(|x|_2) = \int_{0}^{|x|_2} tg(t)dt$. For simple functions $g$ it works (e.g. $g(x) = x$).

I don't know how to show that the derivative of $h$ is: $h'(|x|_2)=g(|x|_2)|x|_2$ in general to finally show $f = \nabla h(|x|_2)$. I have tried integration by parts, but haven't succeeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\Phi$ is to be a potential, it must be true that
$$
\Phi(x)-\Phi(0) = \int_{L(0,x)}f(s)\cdot\mathrm{d}s
$$
Here $L(0,x)$ is the line segment running from $0$ to $x$. Choosing $\Phi(0)=0$ and simplifying the integral, we have:
$$
\Phi(x)=\int_0^1g(t|x|_2)tx\cdot x\mathrm{d}t=\int_0^{|x|_2}u\,g(u)\,\mathrm{d}u
$$
Suppose $|x|_2\neq 0$. Then $|x|_2$ is smooth at $x$ and the integral is a differentiable function of its upper limit as its integrand is continuous. Taking the gradient in spherical coordinates gives (keep in mind that the derivative of a definite integral with respect to its upper limit is just the integrand evaulated at the upper limit):
$$
\nabla\Phi(x) = \hat{e}_r\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial|x|_2}=\hat{e}_r|x|_2\,g(|x|_2)=g(|x|_2) x
$$
Here $\hat{e}_r$ is the normed radial basis vector and so $\hat{e}_r|x|_2 = x$.

We have a potential issue at $x=0$ as $|x|_2$ is not differentiable there. However, take $x$ such that $|x|_2<1$. Since $g$ is continuous, it is bounded on $[0,1]:\,\,|g(u)|<M\,\forall u\in[0,1]$ for some constant $M$. We can now estimate for such $x$:
$$
|\Phi(x)|=\left\vert \int_0^{|x|_2}u\,g(u)\,\mathrm{d}u\right\vert\leq\int_0^{|x|_2}u\,|g(u)|\,\mathrm{d}u<M\int_0^{|x|_2}u\mathrm{d}u=\frac{1}{2}M|x|_2^2
$$
But now we can show all the partial derivatives exist and are $0$ by definition, as for each $0<h<1$ we have:
$$
\left\vert\frac{\Phi(h\hat{e}_i)-\Phi(0)}{h}\right\vert<\frac{1}{2}Mh
$$
Since this just means that the difference quotient for $\partial_i\Phi(0)$ vanishes in the limit, we finally have that for all $x$:
$$
\nabla\Phi(x)=g(|x|_2) x
$$
EDIT: Just for the sake of completeness, I should note that while all the partial derivatives of $\Phi$ exist at $0$, this is in general [not enough for differentiability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_in_higher_dimensions). However, it's easy to see that they're all continuous at $0$, and this does suffice for differentiability.